# Protractor - Find all elements and loop length of found elements and click button

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I have been trying to figure out on how to click a button x times depending on how many find All elements are. Meaning if there is 3 elements that is found by the same classname then we loop 3 times which should click the button 3 times.

I have done something like this:

*(New update, check edit post at the bottom)*

Usually the `element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined')).getText()` is 3 but can be changed to 6 and random numbers so my idea was to read first how many `btn btn-remove btn-outlined` are in the HTML and click that many times of found elements. So if 3 found then click the button 3 times.

However the problem right now is that it is finding how many elements there are. It is also looping that many times that is given as text.length but inside the loop it seems to skip the **it** functions for some reasons and I cant figure out why

Right now it does find the length of the elements which is 3 and it seems to loop that many times but it skips to do the it functions (This part):

```
      it('Click remove button - ' + i + '/' + text.length, function (done) {

            browser.driver
                .then(() => browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined').first().getWebElement())));
                .then(() => done());
        });

        it('Wait for fading button to be gone', function (done) {

            setTimeout(function () {
                done();
            }, 1000);

        });
```

and I am afarid that I might have done something wrong that I am not aware of.

How can I find how many given elements are in the DOM and loop that many times + click the remove button?

EDIT CODE:

```
it('Click remove button', function (done) {

    element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined')).getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text.length) //returns 3
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            console.log(i); //Does print 0 1 2

            it('Click remove button - ' + i + '/' + text.length, function (done) {

                console.log("Remove button"); //Doesnt print

                browser.driver
                    .then(() => browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined').first().getWebElement())));
                    .then(() => done());
            });

            it('Wait for fading button to be gone', function (done) {

                console.log("TIme out"); //Doesnt print

                setTimeout(function () {
                    done();
                }, 1000);

            });
        }
    })
    done();
});
```

Comment: You have 3 functions named `it`, this could be causing scope issue. Add a print statement inside each `it` function to see what is being called. I would suggest picking new names.

Comment: Also you are defining the `it` functions but where are they being called?

Comment: I think it is a Mocha/Chai function actually. Maybe I should have mentioned it but I will print console.log on each and see what it respons @Jortega

Comment: @Jortega https://samwize.com/2014/02/08/a-guide-to-mochas-describe-it-and-setup-hooks/

Comment: @Jortega I just updated the code. I added comments through each console.log. It seems like the `it` functions never starts inside a loop.

Comment: My advice to you, test your code first. Create your nested `it` blocks with `console.log` only. If works, create one it block to click whatever... if that works too, combine them together

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov It seems like you know how I would like to have but I am not sure on how to combine it? Basically the idea is to first look how many elements there are and then use a for loop to click x times pending on how many elements were found. When I split it into 3 blocks for each IT function then it works but I am not able to have a for loop inside a IT then. Maybe you could give me a advice or example on how to combine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your `it` inside for loop not executed is those `it` generated dynamically in run time and did not respected by the test framework, Jasmine, Mocha.

As I learned, Jasmine need to load and parse the static `it` in test script files before executing them, dynamic `it` generated behind the load and parse stage will be ignored. Thus you need remove dynamic `it`.

Try below code

```
it('Click remove button', function (done) {

    let allBtns = element.all(by.className('btn btn-remove btn-outlined'));

    allBtns.count()
    .then(function (cnt) {

        console.log('Find buttons:', cnt)

        for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) { // important to use let but var here.
            console.log('Remove button - ' + i + '/' + cnt);
            browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", allBtns.get(i).getWebElement())
            browser.sleep(1000) // sleep 1s
        }
    })
    .then(()=>{
        done();
    })

});
```

Comment: Oh my! This was exactly what I was looking for! I really apprecaite it yong! WIll mark this as the answer and I do understand it more and more. Seems like you cant have nested it functions which I thought you could.

Comment: You can have nested `it`, but they should be `static`.  `static` here means when Jasmine load test script files before any it be executed, after parse Jasmine will know how many it in given  test script files, only these it are static it.  In your code, Jasmine can't count the `it` inside your loop when load and parse, because only when Jasmine executing this script file, you can know how many buttons is there and how many dynamical it should be increased.  But jasmine will ignore them

Comment: Oh right, I am running through mocha and chai but I believe its the same thing. But I do understand the reason now and understand how to solve it. I do have another problem but I am currently writting it on another thread, do you want me to address it to you? It is similar but abit more advanced I would say. If you have time over? as I already have entered this as the correct answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206145/how-to-read-elements-values-and-click-amout-of-time