# How to read elements values and click amout of time

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, mocha.js, chai

So I am currently working on reading elements and a situation can be that it says example on the tag:

```
<div class="stock-controller" style="transition: border-bottom 0.3s ease 0s, opacity 0.3s ease 0s;">
    <div class="message">
        <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path fill="#E00751" d="M14 7A7 7 0 1 1 0 7a7 7 0 0 1 14 0z"></path>
                <path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M8.45 7.036L10.414 9 9 10.414 7.036 8.45 5.07 10.414 3.657 9l1.964-1.964L3.5 4.914 4.914 3.5l2.122 2.121L9.156 3.5l1.415 1.414L8.45 7.036z"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>Sorry, we only have 10000 of this product.</div> //Need to read here how many avaliable products
    <div class="quantity-input invalid">
        <button class="btn left" aria-label="Decrease"> //How many user have choose - how many in stock = amout of click time.
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 11h10v2H7z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
        <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" min="0" max="10002" value="10002"> //Need to read how many we have choose
        <button class="btn right" aria-label="Increase" disabled="">
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13 17v-4h4v-2h-4V7h-2v4H7v2h4v4z"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

basically we have 3 tags to look here. the first one is to check the text to see how many products there are in stock and in this case its 10000. Then we have to check how many items a user have choose which is 10002. So we need to use 10002- 10000 = Click this many items on `<button class="btn left" aria-label="Decrease">`

What I have done so far is:

```
it('Check descrease button', function (done) {

    let allBtns = element.all(by.className('stock-controller'));

    element.all(by.className('stock-controller')).each(function (element, index) {
        // Will print  Sorry, we only have 4 of this product., Sorry, we only have 10000 of this product.
        element.getText().then(function (text) {
            console.log(index, text);
        });
    });

    allBtns.count()
        .then(function (countElement) {

            console.log('Find decrease buttons: ', countElement)

            //for (let i = 0; i < countElement; i++) { // let variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { }
                //browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", allBtns.get(i).getWebElement())
                //browser.sleep(1000) // sleep 1s
              //}
        })
        .then(() => {
            done();
        })

});
```

The other problem is that it can be more than 1 stock-controller. So it means it can be etc 5 stock-controller but the all have the same elements but different product in stock and what user have choose.

So my question is:

How am I able to read how many stock-controller there is and then check how many times I need to click decrease button for each stock-controller?

Worked code:

```
it('Clicked all decrease button', function (done) {

    let allProds = element.all(by.css('div.stock-controller'));

    allProds.count()
    .then(function (cnt) { // amount of products

        for(let index=0;index<cnt;index++) {

            let section = allProds.get(index),

                // message string which include qty in stock
                stock_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.message')).getText(),
                // user inputed qty 
                user_qty_str = section.element(by.css('input[type="number"]')).getAttribute('value'),
                // button Descrease
                btn_dec = section.element(by.css('button[aria-label="Decrease"]'));

            Promise.all([stock_qty_str, user_qty_str])
                .then(function(data){
                    // use RegExp to extract qty in stock
                    let group = data[0].trim().match(/^Sorry.*?(\d+)/)

                    if(group) {
                        let stock_qty = group[1] * 1,
                            user_qty = data[1].trim() * 1,
                            gap = user_qty - stock_qty; // click times of Decrease button

                        for (let i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
                            browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btn_dec.getWebElement());
                        }
                    }
                })
        }

    })
    .then(()=>{
        done();
    })

});
```

Comment: Please give an screenshot of your page and add notes in screenshot to give more explain what your what to do.  It's hard for us to get your purpose only from HTML code and description, also hard to build the concept of stack controller, product, item in mind by imaging.

Comment: Oh sure. I will add that soon. 20min.

Comment: @yong Is that good enough? or am I missing something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, give explain inline

```
it('Click remove button', function (done) {

    let allProds = element.all(by.css('div.stock-controller'));

    allProds.count()
    .then(function (cnt) { // amount of products

        for(let index=0;index<cnt;index++) {

            let section = allProds.get(index),

                // message string which include qty in stock
                stock_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.message')).getText(),
                // user inputed qty 
                user_qty_str = section.element(by.css('div.quantity-input input'))
                                      .getAttribute('value'),
                // button Descrease
                btn_dec = section.element(by.css('button[aria-label="Decrease"]'));

            Promise.all([stock_qty_str, user_qty_str])
                .then(function(data){
                    // use RegExp to extract qty in stock
                    let group = data[0].trim().match(/^Sorry.*?(\d+)/)

                    if(group) {
                        let stock_qty = group[1] * 1,
                            user_qty = data[1].trim() * 1,
                            gap = user_qty - stock_qty; // click times of Decrease button

                        for(let i=0;i<gap;i++) {
                            btn_dec.click();
                            browser.sleep(1000).then(function(){
                                console.log('Click Decrease button: ' + i + '/' + gap)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })

        }

    })
    .then(()=>{
        done();
    })

});
```

Comment: Before I start and try since I am currently in the meeting. Do I need to install something with Promise or is it a default package inbuilt?

Comment: I just tested it and it seems like it didnt decrease any button. The error that returns is: `ReferenceError: i is not defined`

Comment: And that is because of your `let section = allProds.get(i),` but I changed the `i` to `index` however the next problem is going to be `ReferenceError: selction is not defined` which I believe is `btn_dec = selction.element(by.css('button[aria-label="Decrease"]'));` ? - I changed that to section aswell but that returned ` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, div.quantity-input input.number)`

Comment: I changed to `section.element(by.css('input[type="number"]')).getAttribute('value'),` and it seemed to work better. I updated my answer and it is working correct now. However I tried to run through IE. I do get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedOperationError: Error 404: Not Found` ?

Comment: Hello yong! it seems like I do still have a problem with this again. The problem is that it says that the test is passed even though it haven't entered all clicks yet: Picture: https://i.imgur.com/p1DXG9w.png

Comment: @yong I believe the issue can be that it doesnt return the promises and instantly take it as its finished?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into protractor, but in java i would do a list of WebElements with xpath like //div[@class='stock-controller']

Then foreach of stock-controllers read amount to click and do it.

```
Pseudocode:
    List stockcontrollers = findby.xpath(//div[@class='stock-controller')
foreach(item in stockcontrollers)
{
get.item
read amount to click
for(x<amount to click)
{click}
}
```